# Why doesn't capture="user" change my phone's camera to front facing?

Tags: android, html, mobile-chrome, mediacapture

I tried the following attribute `capture` to set the `input` element to try to select the front facing camera. `user` is front facing, and `environment` is back facing.

However, while experimenting with Chrome (latest) on mobile (Pixel 1, latest OS), the back camera is still selected.

I used an example snippet:

```
<form action="server.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture="user">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

(from https://w3c.github.io/html-media-capture/#the-capture-attribute)

I am able to change `accept` to require `video` on my phone, so that and other attributes work, but not the `capture` attribute.

**EDIT**: Am using the latest Android Chrome browser. The following page implies that iOS and older versions of Android Chrome cannot use `capture` altogether, but otherwise can use `capture`. https://caniuse.com/#search=html-media-capture

Comment: Surely it's possible that Chrome just hasn't implemented that functionality?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but I am not able to prove it. Added edit to post for more info. Wish this was documented more clearly.

Comment: I would say the "proof" is that it's not working. I'll try to find some _official_ documentation one way or the other.

Comment: Ok. I am new to HTML. Not working isn't a good litmus for a novice, when many things can break when implemented incorrectly.

Comment: Ah, I assumed you were relatively experienced based on the type of thing you were trying to do. As a rule of thumb, though, a code example from the W3C spec should absolutely work if implemented.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know that this is the exception.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I cloned the [chromium repository](https://github.com/chromium/chromium) today (2019-07-21). I then used [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) to get a list of files that do *not* contain `capture`. After passing that list to `rm`, I removed any directories that were either empty or clearly irrelevant (such as telemetry). Going through the remaining ~50 files was a relatively trivial task.

Hopefully the Chrome team will get around to implementing this in the future, but there is currently **no indication that this behavior is supported** in official documentation, official blog posts, or the code itself.

I know it's not the answer you'd like to hear, but those are the facts as I've found them.

Comment: This sounds pretty definitive. Good idea to look at the code itself.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some tests, I included user agent:

**Didn't worked with :**

- Android Chrome: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Ilium X510) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.143 Mobile Safari/537.36
- Android Firefox: Mozilla/5.0 (Android 6.0; Mobile; rv:68.0) Gecko/68.0 Firefox/68.0

**Worked with :**

- IPhone Chrome: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/75.0.3770.103 Mobile/15E148 Safari/605.1
- IPhone Safari: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1

**In Summary:**

- All tested iPhone navigators displayed the front camera view when capture is user, and back camera view if it is environment.
- Both tested Android navigators displayed always the back camera view.

So regardless the information in the accepted answer, it doesn't seem to be a browser issue. It would be helpful if it works correctly with an Android device and a specific browser.

I hope other people can share tests on their Android devices, in particular on working ones, displaying front camera view while testing the capture="user" attribute-value.

Comment: It _is_ a browser issue. The specification says that this should work, and it doesn't. And there is _zero_ code in Chrome, which is the one in question.

Comment: still it works well at Chrome in iPhone, despite the zero code in chrome. Perhaps this exclusive code for iOS is not documented.

Comment: That's because all browsers on iPhone use Safari's engine, per Apple's requirements. Note that I didn't search for _documentation_, but the code itself, as well.

Answer (score 2):

Would it be Chrome specifically that hinders the code from working properly? I suggest using a different browser such as Firefox in order to test this theory. If it does succeed on Firefox, then the simple answer is: Chrome has yet to implement it yet.

Comment: Thanks. Firefox does not produce the desired behavior as well (it's documented anyways). This page implies that iOS Safari and older versions of Android Chrome cannot use `capture` altogether (I am on latest Android), but otherwise can use `capture`. https://caniuse.com/#search=html-media-capture

Comment: Answers should be more than a guess, _especially_ with a bounty attached.